# Eliminar carácter especial "\" en un objeto

Tags: javascript, json

```
{\"x\":42,\"y\":510,\"cadena\":\"Lima, 11 de setiembre de 2017\",\"alineacion\":\"left\",\"size\":10,\"page\":12}
```

Answer (score 1):

El caracter **\** (backslash) se utiliza para imprimir caracteres especiales seguidos de esta. En el caso de el caracter **"**, como este se usa para delimitar el inicio y final de string, en el caso de que este caracter forme parte de string se pone el caracter \ delante.

Si tienes una cadena con ese valor, puedes reemplazar **\"** por **"** en javascript con:

```
cadena.replace('\"','"');
```

Comment: Buenas Juan. Aun que sabemos que la intención es buena, es mejor no responder este tipo de preguntas, dado que falta información. Por poner javascript como etiqueta no quiere decir que necesariamente funcione con javascript y lo mismo no es compatible. Solicita primero al OP que aumente la información para poder dar una respuesta detallada.